# panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`

Tags: polkadot, rust, substrate-parachain-template

I am having a setup of relay chain and two parachains are connected to it, I was running some test cases and during that i encounter an error

```
thread 'test::collection_transfer_fails_for_nonexistent_collection' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Err(Module(ModuleError { index: 7, error: [2, 0, 0, 0], message: Some("NoSuchCollectionId") }))`,
 right: `Err(Module(ModuleError { index: 6, error: [2, 0, 0, 0], message: Some("NoSuchCollectionId") }))`',
```

Here message is same on left and right side but the test fails due to difference in index.Could anyone help me in solving this issue.

Comment: I think the indices are different at `index: 7,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index number is the index of the pallet in the runtime from which the error originated. So it looks like you are expecting the error `NoSuchCollectionId` from the pallet with index 7 and you are getting the `NoSuchCollectionId` from the pallet with index 6.

If you go to your Runtime file you can see which pallets have this index, for example in the substrate-pallet-template the pallet_balances has the index 10 and  the pallet sudo the 15, [see the code](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L467).

In your test you can check if you are receiving an error from another pallet, an example is in the Bounty pallet [See the code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/bounties/src/tests.rs#L260):

```rs
type TreasuryError = pallet_treasury::Error<Test>;

assert_noop!(
            {
                #[allow(deprecated)]
                Treasury::propose_spend(RuntimeOrigin::signed(2), 100, 3)
            },
            TreasuryError::InsufficientProposersBalance,
);
```